# I cannot find anything that is impure about my function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, pure-function

Seriously, I'm getting desperate finding what the issue is. I can't find the answer for days!

`React.StrictMode` API causes our `setState` to be called twice, right? If it produces an error, then it means that somewhere in our `setState` callback is impure. So, which one is it?

```js
setOrganization((initialValue) => {
    const newOrganization = { ...initialValue };

    const oldIssues = [...newOrganization.repository.issues.edges];
    const newIssues = [...data.data.organization.repository.issues.edges];

    newOrganization.repository.issues.edges = [...newIssues, ...oldIssues];

    return newOrganization;
});
```

- On the first call, `oldIssues` is returning the expected value, for example, `[{id: issue1}, {id: issue2}]`. `newIssues` value is for example `[{id: issue3}]`
- But on the second call, the `oldIssues` strangely turn into the combination of `oldIssues` and `newIssues`. (second call, `oldIssues` **IS ALREADY** `[{id: issue1}, {id: issue2}, {id: issue3}]`).
- Making the second `newOrganization.repository.issues.edges` value has a doubled `newIssues`. `[{id: issue1}, {id: issue2}, {id: issue3}, {id: issue3}]`

Full script can be found here, on line 101: https://pastebin.com/ugsrBRTM

Comment: `newOrganization = { ...initialValue };` does a shallow copy of your object, so `initialValue` is still being modified

Comment: Really? I just know that. Any recommendation I can fix it?

Comment: Ohh, forget what I just asked. A silly question. I can just google it. Thank you ️

Comment: Holy smokes! I just changed the code to `const newOrganization = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialValue));` and BAM! It works like charm! Thank you for informing me this. You have my gratitude.

Comment: no worries  glad you got it all worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nick Parsons' comment above, I just know that *object spreading* **only performs a shallow copy**. All I need to do is to change the copy method to **deep copy**.

I found the method here: [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)